# How to understand this representation of group on cone of symmetric matrices?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-actions

I am reading the following paper:  https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211450.pdf (p.7) (Reading that page from "In several application domains" is pretty enough.)

In particular, the following part:

[image]

My understanding is:

$\rho(g)$ is an element in $GL(\mathbb{R}^N)$, $\rho(g)$ should **act** on a vector $v\in \mathbb{R}^N$, also can be written as $\rho_g(v)$. However, $X\in \mathcal{S}^N$, which is a symmetric matrix not a vector.

I am confused about this concept.

Comment: Elements of $GL(R^N)$ are matrices and we can multiply matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have that $\rho$ is a homomorphism from $G \to \mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$. Now $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbb{R}^{N})$ is a group, which can give many different group actions. The natural action is on $\mathbb{R}^{N}$ by left multiplication, but it can *also* act on the set $\mathcal{S}^{N}$ of symmetric matrices by conjugation. You can verify that this does indeed provide an example of a group action.